# wxpython boxsizer addmany spacer

Tags: python, wxpython, boxsizer

How can I add a spacer between two items in a boxsizer, while using Add Many?
I tried key words like Spacer, AddSpacer and things like that but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AddMany just calls Add, so if you pass (10, 10) as the first item of the tuple, it will be interpreted as a spacer, right? Like:

```
AddMany(
    (some_widget, flag=wx.EXPAND),
    ((10, 10),),  # this is a spacer
    (another_widget, flag=wx.EXPAND),
)
```

You can also use a border.

```
AddMany(
    (some_widget, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.RIGHT, border=10),
    (another_widget, flag=wx.EXPAND),
)
```